# Sending parameters from different functions to a function

Tags: javascript, frontend

```
    function layerQuery(objectId) {
    const featureLayer = view.map.layers.getItemAt(0);
    const queryParams = featureLayer.createQuery();
   

    queryParams.where = "objectid=" + objectId;
    queryParams.outFields = ["x", "y", "z"];

    featureLayer.queryFeatures(queryParams).then(function (results) {
      const coords = results.features[0].attributes;
      direction_lookup(Promise, Promise,coords.x,coords.y)
    });
    const objectIdNext = objectId + 1
    const queryParamsTb = featureLayer.createQuery();
    queryParamsTb.where = "objectid=" + objectIdNext;
    queryParamsTb.outFields = ["x", "y", "z"];
    featureLayer.queryFeatures(queryParamsTb).then(function (results) {
      var coordstb = results.features[0].attributes;
      direction_lookup(coordstb.x, coordstb.y,Promise,Promise)
    });
    //console.log(coordstb.x)
    
  }
```

I want to send the four parameters we obtained as a result of the above two functions to the following function.

```
function direction_lookup(destination_x, origin_x, destination_y, origin_y) {
    var compass_brackets, compass_lookup, degrees_final, degrees_temp, deltaX, deltaY;
    deltaX = destination_x - origin_x;
    deltaY = destination_y - origin_y;
    degrees_temp = Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY) / Math.PI * 180;
    

    if (degrees_temp < 0) {
      degrees_final = 360 + degrees_temp;
    } else {
      degrees_final = degrees_temp;
    }

    compass_brackets = ["N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N"];
    compass_lookup = Math.round(degrees_final / 45);
    return [compass_brackets[compass_lookup], degrees_final];
  }

  console.log(direction_lookup(destination_x, origin_x, destination_y, origin_y));
```

The 'direction lookup' function takes four parameters. I want to send these four parameters two by two from different functions. can i do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: what the heck is happening in this code wow

Comment: It looks like you are using some kind of mapping or GIS tool here- when you ask a question it is useful to explain any libraries you are using and also what some of the functions do - for example that `featureLayer.createQuery()` looks like some kind of geodata query tool? It would be good to know which one. If that isn't relevant to your question then can you formulate a simpler version of the code that only includes the relevant parts? When I do this, I often solve the problem for myself just trying to write the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible because your `direction_lookup` function needs those four parameters to be the numeric co-ordinates, it isn't expecting to see any `Promise` objects or resolve them. The standard way to do this is to wait until you know all the values before you call the function, like this:

```
function layerQuery(objectId) {
    const featureLayer = view.map.layers.getItemAt(0);
    const queryParams = featureLayer.createQuery();
   

    queryParams.where = "objectid=" + objectId;
    queryParams.outFields = ["x", "y", "z"];

    featureLayer.queryFeatures(queryParams).then((results) => {
      const feature1Coords = results.features[0].attributes;
      const objectIdNext = objectId + 1
      const queryParamsTb = featureLayer.createQuery();
      queryParamsTb.where = "objectid=" + objectIdNext;
      queryParamsTb.outFields = ["x", "y", "z"];
      featureLayer.queryFeatures(queryParamsTb).then((secondResults) => {
         const feature2Coords = secondResults.features[0].attributes;
         direction_lookup(feature2Coords.x, features2Coords.y,feature1Coords.x,feature1Coords.y);
      });
    }); 
   }
```

Now you perform your first query and keep the results from that in scope while you perform the second query and finally call `direction_lookup` when you have both sets of co-ordinates ready to go.

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) behave like regular functions but maintain the parent scope, which can save a lot of confusion, so for this kind of task it's a slightly more convenient notation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. you helped me understand the problem